# Why annualized return and cumultive return aren't equal over 1-year period with Performance Analytics package in R?

Tags: programming, r, performanceanalytics

I use Performance Analytics package in R to compare annualized and cumulative return of a portfolio. My expectation is that both should be equal over a period of 1-year but results tell me I'm wrong.

It is not clear for me how annualized return could be 122.55 from 2014-01-01 to 2014-12-31 while the cumulative return is 205.71 over the same period. Geometric is set to its default value (`TRUE`) and I think number of period in a year is set by default to 252 (daily scale).

```
statistic <- rbind(Return.annualized(bench)*100, Return.cumulative(bench)*100)
```

To know better what is the return I can expect from this portfolio could somebody please explain to me why both returns are not equal ?

Comment: You should add links to the documentation of the package. Have you had a look there? What does it say about the difference between these two methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation of the R package [PerformanceAnalytics](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PerformanceAnalytics/PerformanceAnalytics.pdf) provides examples for both the `Return.annualized()` and `Return.cumulative()` functions.

The annualized return scales up sub-annual returns to an annual return. You may observe the difference by typing `Return.annualized` (without any parameters) in your R console to see the functions implementation. Look for how the return is calculated if geometric linkage is applied:

```
 if (geometric) {
            result = prod(1 + R)^(scale/n) - 1
        }
```

The cumulative returns are actual returns that are calculated over an annual period. The formula for the calculation is similar, but lacks the scaling piece:

```
else {
            return(prod(1 + R) - 1)
        }
```

If the period being analyzed is exactly one year annualized and cumulative returns are the same:

```
data(managers)
Return.annualized(managers[121:132])
Return.cumulative(managers[121:132,])
```

But if the period is not equal to one year they are expected to be different:

```
data(managers)
Return.annualized(managers[115:132])
Return.cumulative(managers[115:132,])
```

Comment: Thanks. For my Annualized Return to be 122.55 I've found that _n_ must be equal to 352 in prod(1 + R)^(scale/n) - 1 (_n_ is the total number of periods for which I have observation). The consequence is that ratio (scale/n) is different from 1 (with scale = 252). It is not clear what is wrong because `periodicity(bench)` returns `Daily periodicity from 2014-01-14 to 2014-12-31`.

Comment: I get it. _n_ equal 352 because I have saturday and sunday in my dataset ;-) and PerformanceAnalitics is not designed to work with 7 days of trading per week.

Comment: The most frequent assumption for stock returns is that it's 252 trading days in a year. There are other day count conventions but they usually play a larger role when looking at fixed income data since returns would be very often evaluated rather than observed...